# what happens when you load data into hive internal table?

Tags: hive

what happens when you load data into hive internal table ? will the data be copied over from the existing location to a new location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't be copied. During the time of the load, wherever the internal table is pointing to, data will be written there. It also depends on the insert statement - insert into vs insert overwrite.

check the location using

```
desc extended table <tablename>;
```

If you want to change the location, then do

```
alter table <Tablename> set location 'new location';
```